# How to search for the name beginning of the name in the database ... or the end of the name

Tags: c#, sql

I have Database table **name** which has data like this

[image]

Currently I'm doing it like this

```
con = new SqlConnection(cs.DBConn);
con.Open();
cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT full_name from name where name like '%" +      textBox3.Text + "' order by name", con);

rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
while (rdr.Read() == true)
{

    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(rdr[0]);


}
con.Close();
```

Now, I want to search for the name beginning with mark or Michelle ...

Comment: `from name where name like` is this working? what would be the value of `textBox3.Text` and what is your expected result for this?

Comment: It does not work, but give me all the names in the table

Comment: @m.mahmoud First get your data in Dataset or Datatable and bind it to your grid and perform your search operation there on DataTable as this will not send hits to your database again and again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the `LIKE` to work for any part of the name, you need to put `%` on both sides; if you really just want beginning or end (but not middle), you should do a `LIKE '%search' or LIKE 'search%'`.

And either way, you really should parameterize your SQL query to avoid SQL Injection, and wrap your `SqlConnection` and `SqlDataReader` in `using` blocks to make sure it gets disposed of properly if an exception occurs, for example:

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(cs.DBConn))
{
    con.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT full_name from name where name like '%' + @p0 OR name LIKE @p0 + '%' order by name", con); 
    // or perhaps just "where name like '%' + @p0 + '%' order by name"
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p0", textBox3.Text);
    using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
        while (rdr.Read() == true)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(rdr[0]);    
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, keep in mind that if your textbox is blank this will match all rows in your table...

Comment: Are you sure `@p0` and ` cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p0", textBox3.Text);` is enough to supply two parameters?

Comment: he only needs one parameter, but in that version of the query the same parameter is getting used twice. ADO.NET will convert that to something like `DECLARE @p0 VARCHAR(MAX) = 'sometext'; SELECT .. WHERE name LIKE '%' + @p0` etc.

Comment: cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT full_name from name where name like '% @d'", con);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d", textBox3.Text); not work

Comment: condition to declare parameter >>>>???? i use these code and work with me if name like full word